# Why Item Updated and Item Added trigger together when we add a item to list (document library)

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, event-receivers

I have gone through hundred of articles over months but never understood as what could be the reason Item Updated and Item Added trigger together when we upload a item, even though if you try  `this.DisableEventFiring();`

Can someone with deep knowledge of sharepoint point me in right direction, I have gone through similar questions but non of them are effective.

And if `Item Updated` have to trigger on Item Added then I wonder why Microsoft bothered creating `Item Added` event at all ?

Comment: Are the documents being loaded Office Documents?

Comment: @SimonDoy yup they are

Comment: I seem to remember hearing about the fact that SharePoint will populate certain fields from Office Documents into the SharePoint List Item. I think its called Property Promotion. Wonder if this is the reason why. I guess you could test this out by uploading a PDF file and see if you get the same ItemAdded ItemUpdated events being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a document to your document library the event ItemAdded was called.
If you work with the standard upload, after that the document has been added, a popup window will be open to insert the metadata of your document, this fires the ItemUpdated event.

Why?
The reason is simple.
When the file is saved, after the ItemAdded event, its metadata will be empty. So when you insert the metadata by the popup you just update those.

Comment: Before you reach "ItemUpdated" screen or form to update meta data of item it triggers ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events.

Comment: I think it is for the same reason. Instead if you updated an item only the ItemUpdated event will be fire

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio is correct, if there is no metadata to be filled for the uploaded document then only ItemAdded event is fired and if there is metadata to be filled, then ItemUpdated event will be fired.