# Why ItemUpdating is calling after ItemAdded event in Sharepoint-2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, event-handlers, splistitem

I am developing Sharepoint 2010 application where I have been using `SPItemEvent` to deal with `ItemAdded` event.

One thing surprised me that `ItemUpdating` event is calling after `ItemAdded` event in List. This is not happening while adding document.

I've checked all my code but I am not able to spot out reason behind it.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that it is happening only for adding new item for list and not for adding (uploading) item (document) to document library?

Comment: Ya, it's only happening while Adding list. I am not adding item programmatically rather than Sharepoint UI.

Comment: I've asked you cause I found this question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59004/why-item-updated-and-item-added-trigger-together-when-we-add-a-item-to-list-doc

Comment: the link marked by @Remon is the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it might owe to Synchronous events as both before and after events can be synchronous. After which the execution order depends on sequence number. This msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858(v=office.14).aspx might be of some help for you.

Also suppose say I am having 2 `ItemAdded` receivers, the order for them would be defined based on the sequence number for the event receivers respectively (The event with lower sequence number gets executed first).

Comment: any explanation for calling `itemUpdating` on adding new item? or reference for this order sequence?

Comment: @Remon Though I also don't have much information about the order, but I have read in **stackExchange** itself this order(once I will find the link, I will add that here). And moreover gong by the sequence number makes more sense to me.

Comment: Thanx for answering. But, my question is that why ItemUpdating event is calling while adding List item where as it does not happening while adding document.