# Workflow for new and modified items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365

I'm creating a Document Library on Office 365.

I've created a Workflow for a Document Library which gets triggered on creating a new Document within the Library.

I've also created a separate Workflow that will get triggered when an existing Document is modified in some way.

Problem is - if someone creates a new Document, both Workflows run. It also seems that when modifying a document for the 2nd time, the modify workflow doesn't execute again.

Is there anyway around this?

EDIT:

I still can't seem to get this working, my statement looks such like:

```
If Current Item:Created equals Current Item:Modified (do nothing) else (Email PersonA). 

The Transition to stage contains "Go to End of Workflow"
```

EDIT 2:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to put the if/else in the `Transition to stage` portion.

Comment: What would then go in the Top Portion, or can that be left empty?

Comment: If it can't be left empty, simply log a comment to history

Answer (score 6):

This is by design.

In Update Workflow just check if Modified Date is equal to Created Date. That means it is an update after new file upload.

Comment: How exactly can I go about achieving that, I am very new to SharePoint!

Comment: In your update workflow as a first statement use `if currentitem:created is equal to currentitem:modified` `then` `stop workflow`

Comment: Would  that be as a step or stage?

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, my statement looks such like: If Current Item:Created equals Current Item:Modified (do nothing) else (Email PersonA). The Transition to stage contains "Go to End of Workflow"

Comment: @PnP `Modified` will not always match `Created` if they have to fill out metadata after the document upload.

Comment: @PnP Try `If Current Item:Created equals Current Item:Modified then Stop Workflow`

Comment: SharePoint Designer 2013 doesn't let me put Stop Workflow at the end of the IF statement...

Comment: See the edit in my question, I need it to be an IF ELSE

Comment: @PnP please add a screen cap of what you have in Designer.  You should be able to put an if/else in the transition to stage portion of a stage.

Comment: See edit for screen cap.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/59005/20615) SE answer explains why this occurs (it's for event receivers, but applies to workflows as well):

> When you add a document to your document library the event ItemAdded was called. If you work with the standard upload, after that the document has been added, a popup window will be open to insert the metadata of your document, this fires the ItemUpdated event.

There's no way to prevent both from running, but you can work around it.  What you can do is add a field to the library.  Your item created workflow will set this field, and your item updated workflow will have to check for it.  If it's set, then the item created workflow has already, and the item updated workflow can run. If not, then the item created workflow has not run, and the item updated workflow should not run.

Answer (score 0):

Or , if it is designer workflow you can just uncheck relevant checkBox.[image]

Comment: This does not come close to achieving what is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you need, it's adapted from something I put together on a list where I had a hidden Title field that I generated based on several fields, and another workflow that was ran at the same time would always create tasks with a value under related item of "(no title)", so I made it wait for the title before starting. Expanding on that concept, I came up with this:

---

Create two "single line of text" fields with a default of blank. Set them to Hidden so the user doesn't put anything in them. Name them "isExistingFile" and "newFileProcess".

### Workflow #1 - when new document is added:

*[Whatever steps you want the workflow to do]*
then
**Wait for** `Current Item:newFileProcess` **to not be empty**
then
**Set** `Current Item:isExistingFile` **to** "Indeed"

### Workflow #2 - when document is modified:

**If** `Current Item:isExistingFile` **is not empty**
*[Whatever steps you want the workflow to do]*
**Else**
**Set** `Current Item:newFileProcess` **to** "Splendid!"

When a new file is uploaded and triggers both workflows, #2 will see that `isExistingFile` is empty and know that this is a new file, so it shouldn't follow the edited file steps; instead, it will just set `newFileProcess` so that #1 can finish. #1 will do what it's supposed to do on a new file, then it will wait however long it has to for #2 to finish before it sets the `isExistingFile` value, guaranteeing that #2 won't see that value the first time it runs for a given file.

Later, when a file is actually modified, #2 will find a value in `isExistingFile` and will carry out the normal steps for a previously-added, newly-modified file.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this behaviour (the two events that fire on upload) by setting the Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited to Yes in the Versioning settings of your library. This way the edit metadata form won't trigger the ItemUpdated event because the file hasn't been checked in after initial upload.

Just be sure to update your workflow to checkout/checkin the document to update metadata otherwise your workflow will fail.

Only drawback: you lose co-authoring since checkout/checkin implies you want sole ownership of the document during editing.